# How can I reference external data providers in phpunit?

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit, composer-php, tdd

I am trying to run some tests using a common data provider in PHPUnit.

See below test:

```
    namespace AppBundle\Tests\Controller;

    use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;
    use AppBundle\Tests\DataProvider\XmlDataProvider;

    class DefaultControllerTest extends WebTestCase
    {
        /**
         * @dataProvider XmlDataProvider::xmlProvider
         * @covers ReceiveController::receiveAction()
         * @param string
         */
        public function testReceive($xml)
        {
            $client = static::createClient([], ['HTTP_HOST' => 'mt.host']);
            $client->request(
                'POST',
                '/receive',
                [],
                [],
                [],
                $xml
            );

            $response = $client->getResponse();
            $this->assertEquals(200, $response->getStatusCode());
        }
    }
```

Now I want an external data provider class:

```
namespace AppBundle\Tests\DataProvider;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

class XmlDataProvider extends WebTestCase
{
    /**
     * @dataProvider
     */
    public static function xmlProvider()
    {
        return array([
            'xml1' => '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><myTestableXml></myTestableXml>'
        ]);
    }
}
```

But when I run phpunit I get:

> 1) Warning The data provider specified for
>   AppBundle\Tests\Controller\DefaultControllerTest::testReceive is
>   invalid. Class XmlDataProvider does not exist
>
> 2) Warning No tests found in class
>   "AppBundle\Tests\DataProvider\XmlDataProvider".

**How do I do this?**

## UPDATE

composer.json autoload snippet for reference:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "AppBundle\\": "src/AppBundle",
        "Tests\\": "tests"
    },
    "classmap": [
        "app/AppKernel.php",
        "app/AppCache.php"
    ]
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Tests\\": "tests/"
    },
    "files": [
        "vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/VarDumper/Resources/functions/dump.php"
    ]
},
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to reference the data provider using the fully-qualified classname:

```
namespace AppBundle\Tests\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

class DefaultControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{
    /**
     * @dataProvider \AppBundle\Tests\DataProvider\XmlDataProvider::xmlProvider
     * @covers ReceiveController::receiveAction()
     * @param string $xml
     */
    public function testReceive($xml)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

#### Autoloading

Also, make sure to adjust your autoload configuration in `composer.json`, so the data provider can be autoloaded (might need adjustment depending on which directory the ’AppBundle\Test` namespace maps to):

```
{
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "AppBundle\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, since you suggest your autoloading configuration looks like this:

```
{
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    }
}
```

you need to adjust your namespace for the presented tests from `AppBundle\Tests` to `Tests\AppBundle`.

**Note** Unrelated to your question, but personally, I can't see a need for the data provider to extend `WebTestCase`.

For examples, see:

- https://github.com/refinery29/test-util#example
- https://github.com/symfony/symfony-demo/blob/master/composer.json#L6-L16

Comment: Thanks, but its still giving me the warning... :/

1) Warning
The data provider specified for AppBundle\Tests\Controller\DefaultControllerTest::testReceive is invalid.
Class \AppBundle\Tests\DataProvider\XmlDataProvider does not exist
`

Comment: Are you actually using `\AppBundle\Tests\DataProvider\XmlDataProvider::xmlProvider()`?

Comment: yes it provides xml to be used in various tests... well... thats the plan. Or do you mean 'use' ing?

Comment: It could well be that the class cannot be found due to a lack of `autoload-dev` configuration in `composer.json`. Can you confirm that `AppBundle\Tests\DataProvider\XmlDataProvider` is autoloadable in a testing environment?

Comment: If the assertion `assertTrue(class_exists(\AppBundle\Tests\DataProvider\XmlProvider::class)` passes, then you should be good to go. Otherwise, a) the autoloading configuration for classes in the test namespace is missing or b) the class name of the data provider doesn't match its location in the directory structure of the project.

Comment: I can't load it in my controller so i guess not. But i do have an autoload definition for it:     
`"autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
}`

Comment: And for `autoload`?

Comment: Adjusted my answer to reflect the possible need to adjust your `composer.json`. As an aside, even though autoloading for development resources might not be necessary in the first place, it's always a good idea to *document* it by providing appropriate `autoload-dev` configuration right from the start. This also has the advantage that it works right away if you start extracting abstract test cases, or - as in your example - external data providers.

Comment: eugh. still can't access it. I have tried defining it in composer.json. Neither my test or controllers can access the class.

Comment: Can you share your autoload configuration in `composer.json` and your directory structure. Looking at https://github.com/symfony/symfony-demo/blob/master/composer.json#L6-L16 suggests different namespaces than you are housing for your tests: `Tests\AppBundle` instead of `AppBundle\Tests`. Either way, it should be consistent for your project.

Comment: And what's the path to `AppBundle\Tests\DataProvider\XmlProvider`?

Comment: oh jesus christ  `/tests/AppBundle/DataProvider/XmlDataProvider` thank you.

Answer (score 2):

**PHPUnit Provider Autoloader**

> Magic helper to autoload CSV, JSON, PHP, XML and YAML data provider in PHPUnit.

**Instalation**

```
composer require henryruhs/phpunit-provider-autoloader
```

**Usage**

Create the TestCaseAbstract for your testing suite:

```
<?php
namespace ExampleProject\Tests;

use PHPUnitProviderAutoloader;

/**
 * TestCaseAbstract
 *
 * @since 2.0.0
 *
 * @package ExampleProject
 * @category Tests
 */

abstract class TestCaseAbstract extends PHPUnitProviderAutoloader\TestCaseAbstract
{
    /**
     * directory of the provider
     *
     * @var string
     */

    protected $_providerDirectory = 'tests' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'provider';
        
    /**
     * namespace of the testing suite
     *
     * @var string
     */

    protected $_testNamespace = __NAMESPACE__;
}
```

Extend from TestCaseAbstract to autoload the ExampleTest{_testMethod}.{csv|json|php|xml|yml} file:

```
<?php
namespace ExampleProject\Tests;

/**
 * ExampleTest
 *
 * @since 2.0.0
 *
 * @package ExampleProject
 * @category Tests
 */

class ExampleTest extends TestCaseAbstract
{
    /**
     * testMethod
     *
     * @since 2.0.0
     *
     * @param string $expect
     *
     * @dataProvider providerAutoloader
     */

    public function testMethod(string $expect = null)
    {
        $this->assertEquals($expect, 'test');
    }
}
```

**Read more**

Related repository: https://github.com/henryruhs/phpunit-provider-autoloader

Example integration: [PHP test](https://github.com/henryruhs/phpunit-provider-autoloader/blob/master/tests/phpunit/Autoloader/PhpTest.php) autoloads [PHP class provider](https://github.com/henryruhs/phpunit-provider-autoloader/blob/master/tests/provider/Autoloader/PhpTest.php) and [PHP method provider](https://github.com/henryruhs/phpunit-provider-autoloader/blob/master/tests/provider/Autoloader/PhpTest_testMethod.php)